# foreach() can't load packages in personal folder

Tags: r, doparallel

I am having issues running my old scripts. My `foreach()` functions don't seem to have permissions to access my personal library in my Documents folder

Here is my code:

```
foreach(i=1:length(x), .combine="rbind", .packages = c("data.table", "xts")) %dopar% {...
```

My error message is:

```
Error in e$fun(obj, substitute(ex), parent.frame(), e$data) : 
  worker initialization failed: package or namespace load failed for 'data.table' in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...):
 unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/---/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/data.table/libs/x64/datatable.dll':

LoadLibrary failure:  Access is denied.
```

I previously had to create an .Rprofile file in my Documents folder (my default working directory) to point `.libPaths()`to my Documents library directory in order for packages to install and load properly for the base script.

`.libPaths()` gives me:

```
> .libPaths()
[1] "C:/Users/---/Documents/R/win-library/3.5"
[2] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.5.1/library"
```

Package load worked fine for the rest of the script. It just dies when it gets to `foreach()`

Is there any reason it wouldn't have the same permissions as the rest of the script? Do I need to do something with my `.libPaths()`?

Comment: How did you install the package? I seems that `foreach`does not look at your  .Rprofile. Did you try to install the library in `C:/Program Files/R/R-3.5.1/library` ?

Comment: An `access denied` error to me does not indicate an issue with `.libPaths`: if it weren't found, it would say as such. I just tried `foreach` with a `parallel` cluster (16 nodes), loading the `data.table` package multiple times, and it worked without causing that error (win10, R-3.5.3). Have tried (after closing R, unfortunately) deleting (or moving out of the way) the `.../win-library/3.5/data.table/` directory completely and reinstalling it back in R?

Comment: foreach is installed in my `~/Documents/R/win-library/3.5` folder as I don't have write permissions to my C drive. I'm now suspecting that it's attempting to access both directories and that's what is causing the issue.